# Kate wrap selected text

Tags: microsoft-word, kate

Before exposing my problem, I know that there already has been a [post](https://superuser.com/questions/420450/kate-add-quotation-marks-or-square-brackets-or-parentheses-to-selected-word-v) on this, but it didn't work. When I select a text and type `(` or `)` the text is just being replaced with `()`, even though, as indicated in the post, the `Auto Brackets` option is on.

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a possibility to script it:
http://kate-editor.org/2009/10/29/extending-kate-with-scripts/

similar answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11885675/1237439